# Cannot compile depends library- bitcoin v0.21.0

Tags: bitcoin-core, compiling

I'm trying to compile the depends library of bitcoin v0.21.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.
When I'm running the make command, I'm receiving this error:
`funcs.mk:265: *** empty variable name.  Stop.`

What is the meaning of the error and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Can you give the exact commands you're running, and the full output (or at least, the last few lines of it). It's very hard to say based on just what you're giving here. Also note that v22.0 was just released; maybe you want to try that instead.

Comment: @PieterWuille the exact command is `make -C ./deploy`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> funcs.mk:265: *** empty variable name.  Stop.
> ```

> **What is the meaning of the error ...**

It means that line 265 of `funcs.mk` contains an equals sign but the item to its left is not a valid variable name. `Stop` means `make` was unable to continue due to this error.

> **... and how can I resolve it?**

By studying line 265.

Likely there is something earlier or externally that causes some construction here to not contain what it should.

You may need to ensure you have the latest versions of make and other resources using something like `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

> the exact command is `make -C ./deploy`

Maybe your intention is to run `make -C ./depends` ?